# $.ajax equalivant for $.load content filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery lets me filter content when using `$.ajax()`'s shorthand `$.load()` like following:

```
$('#foo').load('/path/to/foo.html #navigation li');
```

How do implement this same functionality using $.ajax(); ?

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'nextpage.php',
    /* get me some specific elements */
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'nextpage.php',
    // …
    success: function(result) {
        $('#foo').html($(result).find('#navigation li').get(0));
    }
})
```